# If string starts with 8 characters with a dash "-" insert specific label

Tags: sql, string, case, sql-like, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In SQL (specifically in Snowflake), I have a string that looks like this:

```
Col_A
afdafe12-123-42141
jkk121jd-313-129en
dje-332-djak
```

How do I make a rule where if the pattern begins with 8 characters with a "-" it is labeled as "keep"?

I want to do a case when statement similar to below:

```
case when Col_A "regex rule" then 'keep' 
when Col_A like 'dje%' then 'remove' else 'disregard' end new_col
from dataframe
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "with a dash". Do you mean "followed by a dash"? In that case: `^.{8}-` is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use 8 underscores. An underscore matches a single character

```
case when Col_A like '________-%' then 'keep' 
     when Col_A like 'dje%' then 'remove' 
     else 'disregard' end as new_col
```

Tip: Snowflake also supports `ilike` which is a case insensitive `like`. You can swap it out if appropriate

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
col_a rlike '^.{8}-'
```

Breakdown:

```
^      beginning of the string
.{8}   any 8 characters
-      a dash
```

Or if you want the first dash to be located in 9th position in the string:

```
col_a rlike '^[^-]{8}-'
```

... where `'[^-]'` means: any character other than `'-'`.